# Android fastest way to read multiple files?

Tags: android, linux, file

I'm writing an android app, and i need to read 7 SYSTEM files at start up. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

This is my code right now and it's pretty slow

read(file1);
read(file2);
...
read(file7);

...

```
public static String read(String file) {
    String fileContents = "";
    try {
        String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", file };
        ProcessBuilder cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Process p = cmd.start();
        InputStream stream = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        fileContents = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
        stream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileContents;
}
```

There has to be some way to cat each file without closing the stream which should significantly speed things up. I tried making a shell script with the 7 cat cmds and reading the output but everything is all mashed together and i can't split the results.

I tried splitting the cat cmds with echo cmds to form a deliminator in the output:

```
cat file1
echo !
cat file2
echo !
```

But the deliminators "!" don't show up in the output and i can't figure out why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you using Java's built-in file reader classes?

Comment: Are your files one line? Just like @Thomas says, you don't need to use Process. This might be the thing that slows it down.

Comment: Just retested with FileInputStream and now is MUCH faster, you guys were right.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try multiple threads. Probably 7 would do just fine, but you have to check if 7 is not too much for the slowest device you are targeting. You need to leave some CPU for UI thread.

Comment: That might be a good solution, i'm not sure creating 7 threads each to read one file would be that much more efficient than what i'm doing now though. It might be worth doing some testing